# GUI of Unity 4.6 - Detecting On Click() Down

Tags: user-interface, canvas, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm using the GUI of Unity 4.6 beta and I need to detect the "On Click() Down" similar to "Mouse Down". The default is mouse up.

[image: "]

Thanks!

Comment: I saw this youtube video after viewing your question. This video is the CORRECT way to do what you're wanting to do. The video is only 10 minutes so I suggest you watch the whole thing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5ZNuM6K27E

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. First remove your `OnClick()` line.
2. Now, at the bottom of the inspector, click **Add Component**.
3. Choose **Event** -> **Event Trigger**.
4. Now **Add New Event Type** to choose a custom event.
5. The event you want is called **Pointer Down**.

Now just add your lines like you did for `OnClick()`.

A section of a video explaining the event handler can be found [here](http://youtu.be/HgT3xoLqMtg?t=47m54s).

Comment: I had the same answer in the forum of unity and works.

Comment: so great.you save my days

Comment: why for me not different with OnClick() ? when i  try print something in log , clicking and down on button not different for me